# Understanding the effects of shared references on a nested data structure

Tags: rust

Ownership Tree

[image: Ownership Tree]

Hi,

I was trying to understand ownership concepts in Rust and came across this image (attached in this post) in "Programming Rust" book.

In particular am concerned about the "Borrowing a shared reference" part. In the book, the author says

> Values borrowed by shared references are read-only. Across the
> lifetime of a shared reference, neither its referent, nor anything
> reachable from that referent, can be changed by anything. There exist
> no live mutable references to anything in that structure, its owner is
> held read-only, and so on. It’s really frozen

In the image, he goes on to highlight the path along the ownership tree that becomes immutable once a shared reference is taken to a particular section of the ownership tree. But what confused me is that the author also mentions that certain other parts of the ownership tree are not read only.

So I tried to test out with this code:

```
 fn main(){                                                                                                    
    let mut v = Vec::new();                                                                                   
    v.push(Vec::new());                                                                                       
    v[0].push(vec!["alpha".to_string()]);                                                                                    
    v[0].push(vec!["beta".to_string(), "gamma".to_string()]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    let r2 = &(v[0][1]); //Taking a shared reference here                                                                                    
    v[0][0].push("pi".to_string());                                                                           
    println!("{:?}", r2)                                                                                      
}
```

I understand that `v[0][0]` cannot be mutable because `v` itself is a immutable shared reference (as a consequence of the shared reference to `v[0][1]`) and the Rust compiler helpfully points it out. My question is that when the author marks certain parts along the ownership tree as "not read only", how can we access these parts to change them?

If my code snippet is not a correct example for what the author intended to convey, kindly help me with an example that demonstrates what the author is trying to imply here. Thanks.

Comment: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: I just created a vector of vectors to simulate the structure in the author's image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are particular cases where you can *split* borrows, creating simultaneously existing references that can be any mix of mutable and immutable as long as they don't overlap. These are:

- Anything where the compiler can statically track the lack of overlap: that is, fields in a struct, tuple, or enum.
- Specifically written `unsafe` code which provides this feature, such as mutable-reference iterators over collections.

Your code as written does not compile because the compiler does not attempt to understand what indexing a `Vec` does, so it does not possess and cannot use the fact that `v[0][0]` does not overlap `v[0][1]`.

Here is program which works with a direct translation of the tree shown in the figure:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Things {
    label: &'static str,
    a: Option<Box<Things>>,
    b: Option<Box<Things>>,
    c: Option<Box<Things>>,
}

fn main() {
    // Construct depicted structure
    let mut root = Box::new(Things {
        label: "root",
        a: None,
        b: None,
        c: Some(Box::new(Things {
            label: "root.c",
            a: None,
            b: None,
            c: None,
        })),
    });

    // "Borrowing a shared reference"
    // .as_ref().unwrap() gets `&Things` out of `&Option<Things>`
    // (there are several other ways this could be done)
    let shared_reference = &root.c.as_ref().unwrap();
    let mutable_reference = &mut root.a;
    // Now, root and root.a are in the "inaccessible" state because they are
    // borrowed. (We could still create an &root.b reference).

    // Mutate while the shared reference must still exist
    dbg!(shared_reference);
    *mutable_reference = Some(Box::new(Things {
        label: "new",
        a: None,
        b: None,
        c: None,
    }));
    dbg!(shared_reference);

    // Now the references are not used any more, so we can access the root.
    // Let's look at the change we made.
    dbg!(root);
}
```

This program is accepted by the compiler because it understands that struct fields do not overlap, so the root may be split.

It *is possible* to split borrows of vectors — just not with the indexing operator. You can do it with pattern matching, mutable iteration, or with `.split_at_mut()`. Here's that last option, which is the most “random access” capable one:

```rust
fn main() {                                                                                                    
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    v.push(Vec::new());
    v[0].push(vec!["alpha".to_string()]);
    v[0].push(vec!["beta".to_string(), "gamma".to_string()]);
    
    let (half1, half2): (&mut [Vec<String>], &mut [Vec<String>]) =
        v[0].split_at_mut(1);
    let r1 = &mut half1[0];
    let r2 = &half2[0];

    r1.push("pi".to_string());
    println!("{:?}", r2);
}
```

This program works because `split_at_mut()` contains `unsafe` code that specifically creates two non-overlapping slices. This is one of the fundamental tools of Rust: using `unsafe` inside of libraries to create sound abstractions that wouldn't be possible using just the concepts the compiler understands.

With a pattern match instead, it would be:

```rust
    if let [r1, r2] = &mut *v[0] {
        r1.push("pi".to_string());
        println!("{:?}", r2);
    } else {
        // Pattern failed because the length did not match
        panic!("oops, v was not two elements long");
    }
```

This compiles because the compiler understands that pattern-matching a slice (or a struct, or anything else matchable) creates non-overlapping references to each element. (Pattern matching is implemented by the compiler and *never* runs Rust code to make decisions about the structure being matched.)

(This version has an explicit failure branch; the previous version would panic on the `split_at_mut()` or on `half2[0]` if `v[0]` was too short.)

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I was just starting out with Rust after having programmed in C++ for a long time. I looked up split_at_mut (the unsafe code there is pretty much what we are so used to having in C++) and pattern matching and realized that I still have a long way ahead. Lovely answer. Thanks for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: "Now, root and root.a are in the 'inaccessible' state because they are
    borrowed. (We could still create an &root.b reference)". How can we take a reference to root.b if root is 'inaccessible'?

Comment: @Srikar When I say `root` is “inaccessible” I mean you can't create any borrows of (or move) the _whole_ of `root`. You can still take `&root.b` because it doesn't care about the whole of `root`, only `root.b`, and there is no exclusive (mutable) borrow of `root.b` so it isn't excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Someone should probably check my answer, as I am fairly new to Rust myself.
But...

I think this is because a Vec doesn't uphold the same invariance as, say, a tuple or nested structs.

Here's a tuple version of the example you gave (Although tuples don't support pushing, so I'm just incrementing an integer):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = (((1, 3), (5)));

    let r2 = &v.0.1; //Taking a shared reference here
    let v2 = &mut v.0.0;
    *v2 += 1;

    println!("{:?}", r2);
}
```

The above compiles. But if you attempt to borrow: `let r2 = &v.0.0;`, you'll get the same error as before.

Now, if you want to actually use nested vectors for trees. There are some crates to help with that, which do not incur runtime costs. Namely token_cell (or its inspiration, ghost_cell):
https://docs.rs/token-cell/1.1.0/token_cell/index.html
https://docs.rs/ghost-cell/latest/ghost_cell/

Here's the example with a token_cell wrapping the vec tree structure:

```rust
use token_cell::*;

generate_static_token!(Token);
fn main() {
    let mut token = Token::new();
    let token2 = Token::new();
    let v = TokenCell::new(vec![vec![
        vec!["beta".to_string()],
        vec!["gamma".to_string()],
    ]]);
    let r2 = &v.borrow(&token2)[0][1]; //Taking a shared reference here
    v.borrow_mut(&mut token)[0][0].push("pi".to_string());
    println!("{:?}", r2)
}
```

I hope this clears some confusion up at least.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The example related to tuples was related to what I was looking for. But since the image in the book mentioned those parts in the ownership tree as being on the heap, I went ahead and used a vector of vectors. The other answer clarifies why it won't work on vectors and how it can be made to work on vectors as well just like you did. So I am accepting that answer. Thanks a lot but.