# Understanding Shared Reference as mentioned in "Programming Rust" book Chap 4

Tags: rust

From the book

> Shared access is read-only access.
> Values borrowed by shared references are read-only. Across the lifetime of a shared reference, neither its referent, nor anything reachable from that referent, can be changed by anything. There exist no live mutable references to anything in that structure, its owner is held read-only, and so on. It’s really frozen.

[image]

My doubt is this line `nor anything reachable from that referent`. Here the two nodes that are marked `not read-only` are clearly reachable from the referent. So by above definition they should be marked read-only. Why am I arriving at this contradiction?

From my understanding they should be marked `read-only` and yet they are marked as `not read-only`??

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537145/understanding-the-effects-of-shared-references-on-a-nested-data-structure). But that question doesn't enquire about why the two nodes are `not read-only`.